# Carbon: allow timestamp in Carbon::parse

Tags: php

I was wondering, if there is a possibility for `Carbon::parse()` function to allow inputting `timestamp` (string).

There are various string types that Carbon supports, but `Carbon::parse("1589283012")`  gives an error:

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (1589283012) at position 7 (0): Unexpected character

I want the method I use to be most possibly versatile - casting datetime strings to timestamp but also allow the timestamp itself to be passed. All this using the shortest possible way (there are, obviously, methods to do it other way like checking the string for integer casting, etc.).

Comment: Cannot reproduce, getting output `2020-05-12 11:30:12` when using `echo Carbon::parse(1589283012)`.

Comment: Oh, my mistake - it supports integers, not strings with timestamp. Edited the question, as there is still one unsolved case.

Answer (score -1):

Should be:

```
$string;       
Carbon::parse(is_numeric($string) ? intval($string) : strtotime($string));
```

Comment: This would make it even worse. Check what happens when I have `intval("2020-01-01 12:15:00")`. Using carbon wouldn't make sense anymore, as it would only work on timestamps...

Comment: Because you do not mention what you will parse in @KarolSobański

Comment: No need to mention - I have mentioned I want the functionality of Carbon. Check what Carbon is...

Comment: You did exactly what I have stated at the end of my question I want to avoid - checking if the string is castable to integer. I just wanted to know if there is any possibility to resolve the issue just with Carbon configuration, parameters - not in basic PHP.

Comment: I am sure the Carbon creator will not add anything like this in his class because sometime basic PHP is the fastest way that why I mark downvote because I think your quest is not useful, sorry about that.

Comment: This solution however is not the case - you use multiple casts for comparison in your solution, whereas it would be possible to allow for string to integer casting just with one additional, to ones already existing in Carbon.